# RewriteRule for Wildfly 14 behind a proxy -> 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildfly, vaadin

I have a Vaadin 10 App running on wildfly 14 behind a proxy (from my hoster), but I can't reach the root path where my app is deployed (404). If I deploy on a specific path, like "/example", I reach my app.

I guess it's the RewriteRule. Here is my actual rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```

There is more confusion: If I make a request mydomain.com/example/ all goes fine. The request mydomain.com/example leads to localhost:8080/example/.

If I change the rule to:

```
RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://localhost:8080/example/$1 [P]
```

it is the same like a deployment on the root path.

With a non vaadin app, like https://github.com/kumar-shantanu/wildfly-demo-war, and I change to it's path in the RewriteRule, all works fine.

I tried a lot, and to be honest, I don't know much about configuring the RewriteRule.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProxyPass do the job:

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
```